# How to define type for props

Tags: compiler-errors, reason

Code:

```
let component = ReasonReact.statelessComponent("Page");
type matchParams = {.
  id: int
};
type match = {.
  params: matchParams
};
type userProps = {.
  match: match
};
let home = <Home />;
let user = (~props:userProps) => <User id=props.match.params.id />;
let make = (_children) => {
  ...component,
  render: (_self) =>
    <div> <Route key="home" exact=false path="/home" component=home />
    <Route key="user" exact=false path="/user/:id" component=user /> </div>
};
```

Output:

> Unbound record field match

on row

```
let user = (~props:userProps) => <User id=props.match.params.id />;
```

how to define type, what i do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused by `match` being a reserved keyword. You should have gotten a better error message though, and I'd consider this a bug in Reason. To solve it, if you need it to compile to `match` on the JS side, you can use `_match` instead, otherwise just use a different name.

You also (probably) have a few other problems:

1. `let home = <Home />` is not a function like `user`. It will probably need to be `let home = () => <Home/>`
2. You're defining a record type as the `props` that will be given to you by the `component` function. But you'll probably be given a JS object instead of a record. See the [Reason guide](https://reasonml.github.io/guide/language/record#interop-with-javascript) which explains the difference.

Comment: but match is property in react-router, how can I use that if I can't use the match word

Comment: As I said above, use `_match`. BuckleScript will remove the leading underscore from the generated code. See https://bucklescript.github.io/bucklescript/Manual.html#_object_label_translation_convention